# Can't access Azure SQL Database from 1&1 Windows server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure

I host my ASP.NET app on a 1&1 Windows Server. My database is hosted on Azure. My application try to access the database but it doesn't work : "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

I tried to open the firewall of my database to the worl (0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) but nothing.

Here is my connection string :

```
connectionString="Data Source=servername.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=NameDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERID;Password=PASSWORD;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
```

In my local computer it works perfectly and when i hosted my app on azure it worked too. But now, I am lost.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would ensure the proper address is used for the database, then I would also see about ensuring that one and one does not have that port blocked also.

Comment: I called 1&1 and they told me that evrything is ok for them. I think azure block access to the database from outside.

Answer (score 0):

@Z. Mohamed , Here are some steps to troubleshoot Azure SQL connectivity issue you can try to see everything is configured correctly. Some of the common connectivity error messages that you would see while connecting to SQL Azure as listed below:

[image]

- Verify Azure Firewall Settings and Service Availability

Login to your SQL Azure portal, Select your project and then switch to the Firewall setting tab. Verify that the SQL Azure firewall is configured to allow remote connections from the IP address(es) that you will be connecting from.

- Verify that you can reach our Virtual IP

Open a command prompt window and use the PING command to confirm that name resolution successfully translates your logical server name to an IP address. The “Request timed out” message shown below is expected because SQL Azure will never respond to ping requests.

If you encountered difficulties in Section 2 then you are not reaching the VIP and are instead being blocked between your client and the VIP. The below steps may be helpful, but at this point a network investigation by your ISP or network engineer is required

Many firewall products allow individual users and domain administrators to block or restrict outbound access on a specific port and or destination IP address. Therefore it is necessary to check the outbound rules that are defined on the local machine as well as any routers or proxies that are in the network path. Rules must allow outbound access on port 1433 to destination IP address range 65.55.*.*. Most firewalls also allow the specification of DNS names to allow. Network products that might block access include:

For complete guide please [refer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/sql-azure-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide/). Hope it helps.